# Compare each word in a list of word in excel with list of words - Java, VBA, Excel

Tags: java, excel, matching, string-comparison, fuzzy-comparison

i've got a cell in excel, which contains several words, that are separated using a comma; for ex.
**Cell A1 = {*hello*, how, are, *you*, today}**

Then I have another cell, which contains several words as well, see following example

**Cell B3 = {*hello*, I, am, doing, good, and, *you*}**

Now I want to see if any word in A1 is contained by B3. So I need to compare the list elements with each other.

Here the words that are contained by both cells are : **A1 = B3 = {hello, you}**
If at least one word match, it prints 1, else it prints 0.

Do you have a suggestion on how to work on this ? Either using Excel functions or Java would be good. But appreciate any suggestion or idea that gets me started.

Note: The lists of A and B can be quite long. Therefore doing it manually won't work

Comment: You can use APACHE POI in java. (https://mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/, https://howtodoinjava.com/library/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/#:~:text=Apache%20POI%20is%20well%20trusted,MS%20Excel%20files%20using%20Java.)

Comment: There is a lookup function in excel VLOOKUP. Just check this for more information https://www.got-it.io/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/vlookup/check-if-one-column-value-exists-in-another-column

Comment: @cool  thanks for your suggestion. But vlookup expects one word per cell, that's why it won't work in my case, cause there several words in one cell & it is not allowed to split them into one cell one word

Comment: You can split the delimited string in a variety of ways depending on your excel version, and use each as the search or lookup criteria.

Comment: Not sure you can do with formulas, you need to do it in VBA. Take A1, `Split` it, loop through the array of parts, and use `InStr` to check if they have a match in B3

Comment: seems like there is no other way than splitting the words.. Ok, I'll try your idea @CorradoBarbero, hope it'll work out. Thanks to everyone helping!

Answer (score 1):

So I did find a solution, though based on an excel formular...

So first I broke down the words in cell A1 and made a reference table out of it. So each word is in one cell.

Then I had to bring the underlying data into a standard format, so that I could match the data to an existing reference table, for ex. remove unnecessary spaces, if there happens to be a word which is build out of two words (eg. *application performance* --> *applicationperformance*). I did this for all the words in the reference table and cells of B.

In Cell B I inserted a space after every word. So the containing elements look for ex like this
**Cell B6 = {Analytics , ArtificialIntelligence , BigData , Drones , Insurance , InsurTech , Software }**
You see that there is always a space between the word and a comma and after a word like Software. And terms consisting of two words (or more) are concatenated.

After that I can use the formular

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT( -- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$10;$B6)))>0;1;0)
```

to find matches.

[Example with formular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyEzE.png)